# Non obvious costs of context switch

Tags: windows, multithreading, intel, context-switch, tlb

I was trying to explain to someone why the model of using a thread per message stops scaling at high message rates due to the overhead of context switching.  I told them that there are more costs of a context switch than just the overhead of the scheduler and saving/restoring all the registers.  The TLB may or may not be fully/partially flushed on Intel X64 CPU's during a context switch.  It depends on the version of the chip and if the OS takes advantage of the new TLB tags.  Does anyone know if windows supports this?  It also occurred to me that the branch predictor table (I'm assuming there is one on Intel X64) might also flushed.  Does anyone know anything about that?  What else am I missing?

The TLB is not flushed if the context is switched to another thread in the same process.  I am guessing that the branch predictor table would not need to be flushed either.  Is this right?

Comment: Threads also have a memory overhead, and *creating* a thread is a particularly slow operation.

Comment: caches are in play too. Since different thread will use stack in different memory region.

Comment: I would tend to think the scalability limitations, while definitely  partially due to context switch overhead, might be more affected by the actual cost for setting up a new thread - allocation of thread structures, stacks, per-thread variables where thread-specific storage is in use, and other such things. Context switching might just be "fast" relative to all the work required to create (and tear down) many short-lived threads...

Comment: TLB miss or cache miss = 100 cycles. Page fault = 100,000 to 10,000,000 cycles depending on whether disk is involved or not. More threads = more pages = more page faults.